# Solve the inequality for a tight upper bound on $k$?

Tags: inequality

We have 
$$(n-k)^2 - (n-k) \le \frac{n^2}{em}$$
$$n > 0$$
$$ 0 < k \le n$$
$$ n-1 \le m \le \binom{n}{2}$$
$$n,k,m \in \mathbb{N}$$

I would like to solve this to get a tighter upper bound on $k$.
I am able to reduce this to
$$2k - 2nk  \le \frac{n^2}{em} - n^2 + n$$

If I take k common and divide by $(1-n)$ on both sides, the inequality flips since $1 - n < 0$ How should I proceed?

**Edit**: Here $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

Another approach: I tried the method of quadratic inequality as mentioned in the comments. (sadly it doesn't work)

This is the result of the said method.

$$f(k) = k^2 + (1-2n)k + n^2(1 - \frac{1}{em}) - n \le 0 $$

The roots will be
$$k = \frac{1}{2}(2n-1 \pm \sqrt{(2n-1)^2 - 4(n^2(1 - \frac{1}{em}) - n)})$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(2n-1 \pm \sqrt{\frac{4n^2}{em} + 1})$$

We can see that as $k \to \infty$, $f(k) \to \infty$ and as $k \to -\infty$, $f(k) \to \infty$. So if the roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then the inequality is true only if $\alpha \le k \le \beta$

We get $\beta = \frac{1}{2}(2n-1 + \sqrt{\frac{4n^2}{em} + 1}) = n + \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\frac{4n^2}{em} + 1} - 1) > n$

Since we already know that $k \le n$ we can see that $k \le \beta$ does not provide any additional tighter bound on $k$

Comment: Is $e$ the base of the natural logarithm? Also, how did you get $2k-2nk\le\frac{n^2}{em}-n^2+n$?

Comment: rewrite it as a quadratic inequality for $k: \ k^2 + (1-2n)k +n^2-n - \frac{n^2}{en} \leq 0$ and solve. What bounds do you get?

Comment: @mathlove Yes $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm. I expanded the LHS to get $k^2 - 2nk + k \le RHS$ and since $k \le k^2$,  I got $2k - 2nk \le k^2 - 2nk + k \le RHS$

Comment: @Alex That didn't help. Let $f(k) =k^2 + (1-2n)k + n^2 - n - \frac{n^2}{em}$. $f(0) = n^2 - n - \frac{n^2}{em} > 0$ and k > 0. So we will get only a lower bound for $k$ using this method.

Comment: $k=n$ satisfies your system, so you cannot have any upper bound tighter than $k\le n$, can you? Not sure what else you want, unless you want an upper bound for $n$ given some $m$.

Comment: @Macavity the problem is that I want to find a tight upper bound for the value of $k$. $k \le n$ is trivial and I am trying to derive an upper bound on $k$ using the given inequalities which I have derived from the scenario which was given in the original problem (which I have omited from my question)

Comment: A function in terms of $n,m$. As an additional insight. $n$ is actually the number of nodes in a graph, $m$ is the number of edges (the graph is assumed to be connected and an upper bound on $k$ would be the upper bound for a vertex cover in the graph.

This inequality is a by product of trying to use Lovasz Local Lemma to find a vertex cover of size at most $k$ for the graph.

Comment: @Macavity meant to tag you in the comment above

Comment: Suppose you have $k \le f(n,m)$ as a tight upper bound. If $f(n,m)\ge n$, then it is not tighter than the trivial bound. OTOH if $f(n,m)<n$ then it precludes $k=n$ so is not a bound. I fail to see how you can come up with a tighter upper bound. A more complicated one perhaps, but not tighter.

Comment: No, that is my point. We don't know the value of $k$. My objective is not to show that the bound is satisfied for all $k$. I just have to show that a vertex cover of size at most $f(m,n)$ can exist. Since if $k \le f(m,n)$ it implies that Lovasz Local Lemma will be true for at least one subset with size $\le f(m,n)$

Comment: @Macavity if it is given that $k < n$ and if we show that $k < \frac{n}{2}$  it will be consistent with the fact that $k < n$. So what my question is that using all the constraints given in the question, can we show some tighter bound on $k$ apart from what is already given?

Comment: From what you are asking, it almost seems you are infact searching for the minimum positive $k$ which will satisfy the system.  As I am not clear what you really want, I wouldn't want to speculate further on the question or attempt answering something else...